# How to type a new line in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I inserted a `UITextView` into a view controller. I want to set the text to, for example, this:

```
hello
world
```

I *can* just add an outlet to the view controller class and set it like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
myTextView.text = "hello\nworld"
```

But I want to be able to set it directly in interface builder! So I tried the following and they all didn't work!

- typing "hello" and press return
- typing "hello\nworld"
- typing "hello" and shift + enter

I finally tried to write the text somewhere else and copy/paste it into the box and it finally works!

But seriously? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface builder use (option + enter) instead of (shift + enter).

Comment: what does it mean use option + enter this is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

In the interface builder use (alt + enter) or (option + enter).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: already same answer given you must be add as a comment  instead of answer :)

Comment: I have write alt not option. And you are the one who have commented that what is option. :)

Comment: I am not lion, i am Nirav. Check my profile and lion profile. Do not write anything before knowing someone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115474/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-nirav-doctorwala).